# How to create a timer per question using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will like to achieve something in a quiz system.

Right about now I have a quiz system that works perfectly well. It closes the quiz after 10:00 min is elapsed.

But what I want now is, for each of the question there should be a timer. 
So Question 1 would have 10 secs, Question 2 would also have 10 secs down to Question 20.

So when you fail to answer any question within ten seconds, it automatically takes you to the next question.

Right about now, what happens is that you must click on the next question button before it takes you to the next question, which is what I want to change.

Below is the code that does the timer and submit after 10 min

```
<script>
         //function that keeps the counter going
        function timer(secs){
            var ele = document.getElementById("countdown");
            ele.innerHTML = "Your Time Starts Now";         
            var mins_rem = parseInt(secs/60);
            var secs_rem = secs%60;

            if(mins_rem<10 && secs_rem>=10)
                ele.innerHTML = " "+"0"+mins_rem+":"+secs_rem;
            else if(secs_rem<10 && mins_rem>=10)
                ele.innerHTML = " "+mins_rem+":0"+secs_rem;
            else if(secs_rem<10 && mins_rem<10)
                ele.innerHTML = " "+"0"+mins_rem+":0"+secs_rem;
            else
                ele.innerHTML = " "+mins_rem+":"+secs_rem;

            if(mins_rem=="00" && secs_rem < 1){
                quiz_submit(); 
            }
            secs--;
         //to animate the timer otherwise it'd just stay at the number entered
         //calling timer() again after 1 sec
            var time_again = setTimeout('timer('+secs+')',1000);
        }
    </script>


<script>
setTimeout(function() {
        $("form").submit();
    }, 600000);
</script>
```

Here is the code that does the onclick to next question

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.cont').addClass('hide');
    count=$('.questions').length;
    $('#question'+1).removeClass('hide');


    $(document).on('click','.next',function(){
        last= parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
        nex = last+1;
        $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');

        $('#question'+nex).removeClass('hide');
    });

    $(document).on('click','.previous',function(){
        last = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
        pre = last-1;
        $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');

        $('#question'+pre).removeClass('hide');
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("form").submit();
    }, 120000);
</script>
```

Please note that I fetch my questions with Php Mysqli

Comment: Can you explain what is not working with all that code, and what you've tried to debug the problem?

Comment: "that's what I want to change"...so what is stopping you from doing that? What have you tried? What went wrong? As far as I can see from a brief scan of the code you will need to 1) separate the code which moves to the next question out of the click events and into a separate function), 2) change your timer code so it will call the function after 10 seconds, 3) change the event handler code so it calls the function (you'll need a way to maintain the current question ID of course, so the function can use it regardless of how it's called).

Comment: @NicoHaase Like I said in in the question, What I have is working properly, but I am lost on how to make the question go to the next question automatically after 10 seconds. I am unsure of what to change in my current code to achieve that.

Comment: hopefully my comment (below Nico's) gives you a hint then.

Comment: @ADyson yes it does, I am trying that right away.

Comment: Where is PHP and Mysqli code?

Comment: @Dharman I'm pretty sure that won't be relevant here in actual fact.

Comment: @ADyson The SetTimeout keeps submitting the form instead of going to the next question. Any cause for that?

Comment: `$("form").submit();` would be the obvious reason for that, if you haven't yet removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize a timeout into a variable at start. The callback should simulate a click on the next button. Use [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to simulate. It will execute all `click` event listeners associated to the button.

You also have to reset the timer when button is clicked (manually or not).

**EDIT:** After discussing by comments, I guess that you have `<button.next>` tags for each question in your HTML, with a numeric ID. So I propose you to stock in a variable your current progression.

```
// Initializes
let currentQuestion = 1;
let question_timer = setTimeout(question_timeout_callback, 10000);

// Function which simulates the click.
function question_timeout_callback() {
    // Simulates
    $(document).find(`#${currentQuestion}`).click();
}

// your code...

// And in your click event listener:
$(document).on('click','.next', function () {
    // Resets timer
    clearTimeout(question_timer);
    question_timer = setTimeout(question_timeout_callback, 10000);

    // Update question tracking
    currentQuestion++;

    // your code...
});

// Do NOT forget to update .previous buttons with "currentQuestion--"
```

Now, do not forget to ask yourself how you will handle the possibility to come back to the previous question.

Comment: This seem to work but instead of moving to the next question, it submits the form. what could be the cause? :(

Comment: Even when you click manually? If that's the case, you have probably forgot to specify `type="button"` on your HTML.

Comment: When I Click Manually, it goes to the next question, but when the 10 secs elapse before clicking, it submits instead of going to the next question Plus when I click the next question manually the 10 secs does not restart

Comment: Forgot `clearTimeout(question_timer);` in event handler. But that correction will work only for timer restart...

Comment: Clear timer fixed the 10 secs restarting, but the form still submits by it self after 10secs instead of going to the next question, type is `type=button`

Comment: I guessed you have a next/previous button for each question, so the timer simulated clicking on ALL next button, including the last one (which probably submit the form). I revised my answer.

Comment: Honestly, You just saved my life now. Really Appreciate. Worked Perfectly well.

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest different approach.

first, take the time-counting to the backend of your application (so user can't tamper with it).

when user begins quiz, save start time and user identifier into db.

implement timeout (2s interval?) to ask backend, how much time is left.

create simple script which loads remaining time from db (calculates how much time remains for current question) and returns it to the frontend.

php:

```
<?php 
$user = (int) $_GET['user'];
$questionNumber = (int) $_GET['question'];

//connect to the db
//select eg. with PDO
$st = $db->prepare('SELECT start_time FROM quiz_completion WHERE user_id = :user');
$st->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$startTimeRow = $sth->execute();

//calculate remaining time
$elapsed = time() - $startTimeRow['start_time'];
$borderTime = 10 * $questionNumber;

echo $borderTime - $elapsed;
exit(0);
```

with mocked GET & db: https://3v4l.org/MId0K

then in js just call this script with user identifier and question number. when less than zero is returned, move user to the next question.

js:

```
$.ajax('http://localhost/your_php_script.php?user='+user+'&question='+questionNumber).done(
function(response){
 if (response < 0) {
  //move to the next q.
 } else {
  //show remaining time?
 }
});
```

with asking backend to get time, there is risk of waiting too long for an answer from php (when many users are completing the poll)

Comment: of course a knowledgeable user could still tamper with this by killing the ajax call (or the timer which will be needed to make it run regularly). There's also the potential for this to introduce performance issues / deadlocking /  on the server by polling it so frequently, and concurrency / consistency issues on the client if the ajax requests take longer than expected and thus start to overlap.

Comment: the only entirely hacker-proof way to do this timing is to make the whole thing server-side - i.e. moving onto the next question entails a full postback. Of course that only allows a reactive approach (e.g. an answer is deemed invalid if the user took too long). The user could be warned by means of a client-side timer being shown, and a postback could even be forced when it expires, but ultimate control of acceptance/rejection of answer would be based on the timestamps of when the page was loaded and then posted back (so even if the client timer was killed, the server timestamp would be ok)

Comment: Of  course the UX in that scenario is a bit lower-quality, so it'll depend on just how fire-proof the OP really needs this to be - is it just a fun quiz, or is there money / status / qualifications riding on the result? We don't really know.